# ActiveSupport Conflict when running tests

Tags: ruby, rubygems, activesupport

I am facing a little problem... I was about to start some Kata exercices on Exercism.io
and when I run the tests i have a  `Gem:ConflictError`

```
/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2325:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate railties-5.1.4, because activesupport-5.1.5 conflicts with activesupport (= 5.1.4) (Gem::ConflictError)
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:224:in `rescue in try_activate'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:217:in `try_activate'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/minitest/rails_plugin.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:98:in `block in load_plugins'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:92:in `each'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:92:in `load_plugins'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:121:in `run'
  from /Users/john/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
```

I am not sure what to do...

Comment: I removed `activesupport-5.1.5`
it still works for now....

Answer (score 11):

`gem update railties` fixed this for me

Comment: My error `Unable to activate railties-6.0.3.3, because activesupport-6.1.3 conflicts with activesupport (= 6.0.3.3) (Gem::ConflictError)` was solved with `gem update railties`. Thanks for the prompt :)